# Laravel's "logout other devices" feature not working

Tags: laravel, authentication, logout

I'm using Laravel 6.0.4. I was asked to logout users from all devices whenever they log in from a new location. Supposedly, Laravel makes this very easy with this:
https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-6/episodes/7

```
public function logoutOtherDevices($password, $attribute = 'password'){ ... }
```

I can see that the code changes the password hash in the database, but the user is still logged in. So it must be that somewhere in the code I am failing to check that the hash has changed. I'm not an expert, perhaps this is an issue related to guards? Our system has four guards. Could it be that some of the guards are not being authenticated correctly? That the guard is not using the hash from the database but some other system?

So, how do I figure out why Laravel isn't logging people out from other devices? I will share config data if you want, just ask me which data to post

---

Auth.php

```
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'staff'
        ],
       'partner' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'partner'
       ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
       'partner' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => \App\Models\Partner::class,
       ],
        'staff' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => \App\Models\Staff::class
        ],
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'partner' => [
            'provider' => 'partner',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'staff' => [
            'provider' => 'staff',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ]
    ],
```

session.php

```
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => null,
```

Comment: Did you enable the `AuthenticateSession` class in Kernel.php?

Comment: Yes, the class is being called but it always runs into the first if:        
`if (! $request->user() || ! $request->session()) {          return $next($request);     }` this is something I don't understand, does that mean the request has no user, and it also has no session? How is then the authentication implemented?

Comment: you have lots of guards here. show your kernel.php and also your code to logout out. i just implemented the method. may be i can help out.